# rabbitmq and php - Process multiple queues with one worker (broker)

Tags: php, rabbitmq, worker, php-amqp

I have 1000 queues with specific names. so I want to process these queues with one broker. is it possible?

the queue names is stored in mysql db so I should fetch theme and run the broker for each one. and of course it should run asynchronously and should be able to pass the queued item to a idle broker. is this possible? or I should make 1000 files with specific queue names as brokers?

**Update:**
this is a picture of my queues. the queues should run in a parallel manner not a serial one. so the users are producer and the worker is consumer that runs the `send_message()` method;

[image]

Comment: `it should run asynchronously` - which *part* should be asynchronous? Why should it be asynchronous? Do you know what asynchronous is?

Comment: actually its a little bit confusing for me. I updated the question to demonstrate my purpose. please have another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you how to it with [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) library. I must warn you, there is no way to consume messages asynchronously in one process.  Though you can run a few processes that serve a set of queues. They could be divided into groups by the queue importance.

Install the AMQP transport and consumption library:

```
composer require enqueue/amqp-ext enqueue/enqueue
```

Create a consumption script. I assume that you have an array of queue names already fetched from DB. They are stored in `$queueNames` var. The example bound the same processor to all queues but you can set different ones, of course.

```
<?php

use Enqueue\AmqpExt\AmqpConnectionFactory;
use Enqueue\Consumption\QueueConsumer;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrMessage;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrProcessor;

// here's the list of queue names which you fetched from DB
$queueNames = ['foo_queue', 'bar_queue', 'baz_queue'];

$factory = new AmqpConnectionFactory('amqp://');

$context = $factory->createContext();

// create queues at RabbitMQ side, you can remove it if you do not need it
foreach ($queueNames as $queueName) {
    $queue = $context->createQueue($queueName);
    $queue->addFlag(AMQP_DURABLE);

    $context->declareQueue($queue);
}

$consumer = new QueueConsumer($context);

foreach ($queueNames as $queueName) {
    $consumer->bind($queueName, function(PsrMessage $psrMessage) use ($queueName) {
        echo 'Consume the message from queue: '.$queueName;

        // your processing logic.

        return PsrProcessor::ACK;
    });
}

$consumer->consume();
```

More in [doc](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/index.md)

Comment: so if there is some items in foo_queue and baz_queue, the baz Items will process after foo items done? or the have same priority and will process together in multiple worker-process?

Comment: and another thing is if a worker is working on a queue item then another worker will fetch the same item and work on it? or fetch another item?

Comment: The queue consumer switches between the queues all the time. If you have some messages in foo queue and bar queue it will process them in this order foo,bar,foo,bar and so on.

Comment: There is no way to get the message being currently processed. This is RabbitMQ responsibility to control such stuff.

Comment: so if i have 1000 queues the second item in first queue will process after processing of all 999 other queue's first items?

Comment: Yes, it is If you really need one process. You can easily make several processes. The queues that are critical could be executed separately where the others could be grouped.

Comment: The side question. Do you really need 1000 queues?

Comment: actually i want to have multiple users and each users has multiple telegram-bot then they can send broadcast messages. so I thought I can make a queue for each bot and do the messaging but I think its not a good idea? the 1000 queues might be 10,000 so its not the proper design.

Comment: I don't think you need a per-user queue. If I were you I would create two queues: broadcast_message and message_sent. The first contains the message body and a user id who sent it. The second one contains a recipient user id and the same message body. The broadcast_message consumer finds sender recipients and copies them the message by sending it to message_sent queue. The message_sent consumer deliveries the message to the given receipent.

Comment: its a better approach but then, if the recipients of a sender was over 3000 users ,then the second sender's recipients will get the message after 3000 cycle of execution?

Comment: It is valid only If you have one worker process, but you can connect a lot of workers to one queue, and they could even be distributed among several servers processing messages in parallel.

Comment: ok, one last question, is there any other way like cron jobs to run workers? sorry for this long questioning

Comment: The cron job is a bad choose here, you can end up having a lot of processes started by cron. I'd suggest using supervisor or any other process control tool. Or at least a demon, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696877/579025